# String interpolation in raw SQL methods, How is it possible?

Tags: c#

I've just checked the new futures in Entity Framework Core 2.0. There is a really nice feature in it called *"String interpolation in raw SQL methods"* which is described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-0/).

It says that this code:

```
var city = "Redmond";

using (var context = CreateContext())
{
    context.Customers.FromSql($@"
        SELECT *
        FROM Customers
        WHERE City = {city}");
}
```

creates this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE City = @p0
```

It is really strange to me! How `FromSql` method is written as it has just and input of type string.

How does it understand it is an interpolated string, and then create a parameter `@p0` query for it? How can I write a method like `FromSql` aware of how its string parameters are created?

Comment: I'm following C# features 6 and 7, but I haven't heard such feature before!?
How can I write a method like `FromSQL`?

Comment: @mehrandvd while I do not claim to know how they do it, what is happening is that within the method they extract the place holders found within the string create parameters with them and replace the place holders in the string with the parameter names.

Comment: @Vanna my question is about `FromSql`. You mean that it replaces all values with parameters? For example if I had `AND IsActive = 1`, it would create another `@p2`, despite is is not being interpolated?

Comment: @mehrandvd no it would not. the method identifies `{city}` as a place holder but would identify the `1` as a constant/literal value.

Comment: Presumably, `FromSql` accepts a `FormattableString`, not a `string`.

Comment: Another similar question about string interpolation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068194/c6-0-string-interpolation-localization

Comment: Hmmm.. That's it.. `FormattableString` is the one I wasn't aware of. Thank you guys..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way it woks is [`FromSql(` accepts a `FormattableString`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/EFCore.Relational/RelationalQueryableExtensions.cs#L96).

When you use `$"..."` that returns a [`FormatableString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formattablestring(v=vs.110).aspx), that class allows you to inspect the passed in string and see all of the `{ }` blocks inside of and the objects they represent. This allows the framework to replace those `{ }` blocks with a placeholder parameter `@p0` then create a new parameter using something similar to `new SqlParameter("@p0", formatableString.GetArgument(0))`

Comment: Looks like `FromSql` also has [an overload](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/0012a7050ed09a9d447a4289b3052d8564eb512c/src/EFCore.Relational/RelationalQueryableExtensions.cs#L96) that directly accepts FormattableStrring.

Comment: just saw that, updating

Comment: this conflicts with Oracle Text escaping via {}. How to disable this in EF?

Comment: Use double `{{` and `}}` to escape the `{ }`.