# How can I type "{0}" more quickly in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hotkeys, string.format, console.writeline

In C#, it's common to have to type `{0}`, `{1}`, etc. when formatting strings with [`string.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Console.WriteLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx). Considering its frequency, it's an awkward set of key strokes. But despite my searches, I couldn't find any sort of shorthand or hotkey to automatically insert it in Visual Studio. Has anyone figured out something to expedite the process?

Comment: use autohotkey.

Comment: [Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967(v=vs.100).aspx) might be able to do what you want.

Comment: Using C# 6 you can simply place a $ before the string and use our variables directly like this: `string name; string msg = $"Hello {name}"; ` This is also better readable than `{0}`.

Comment: @Lion Indeed interpolation is ideal for non-localizable text (guide - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation), if code must support multiple languages than interpolated strings are  much less useful as currently there is no support for localization - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068194/c6-0-string-interpolation-localization... Which may be the reason OP still using `{0}`.

Comment: You are my idol and hero if that seems to be the issue and obstacle you are facing as a programmer ;)

Comment: @hnefatl, are macros still around or have they been deprecated?

Comment: I'm almost motivated to go and write a VS extension for this :)

Comment: @KyleDelaney Good spot, I didn't notice that. There's an extension [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=XavierPoinas.TextMacrosforVisualStudio201220132015) that seems to provide a good drop-in replacement, though.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I did my research, I included hyperlinks, I was clear and concise, and it's a question that's likely to help other developers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the following command (C#) with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to insert text and then assign a keyboard shortcut to it:

```
    EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
    ts.Text = "{0}";
```

Comment: Get a decent keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

One of the benefits from string interpolation in C#6.0, which I find helps.

Instead of:

```
string s = String.Format("{0} and {1}", variable1, variable2);
```

You can do:

```
string s = $"{variable1} and {variable2}";
```

See a guide: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2422807

Comment: That's good to know! But it doesn't address my question. The $ syntax may be easier to read but it's just as difficult to type because you're still using curly braces. I'm looking for some kind of shortcut or autocomplete.

Comment: Thats not why MS came up with interpolation. Plus it still takes the same amount of keystrokes.