# How do I insert brackets and curly braces in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Noob Question.
What is the shortcut for inserting brackets and curly braces in visual studio?
To look like this
     (){
    
}
I've seen it in a video, but can't remember how to do it.
Thanks in advance.
Anthony.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241777/how-can-i-type-0-more-quickly-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 3):

Type the appropriate keyword and press `tab` key on keyboard twice.

For example, if you type `if` and press `tab` key on keyboard twice, you will see the following code:

```
if (true)
{

}
```

You can try out other keywords like `while`, `try`, `for`,etc.