# Dynamic Resources

Tags: c#, localization, resources

What would be the best way to "fill in" the dynamic properties of a resource file.

Ex.
PhraseId1: "he was going {speed} {unit}"

where speed and unit are determined at runtime.

Currently, I am doing a string replace within my code for each variable. But this feels somewhat cheap (although it works).

In the example, I show two variables, however, in reality, there are over 100 different values that could be substituted in different phrases.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: `"he was going {0} {1}"` `String.Format`

Comment: You might also be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068194/c6-0-string-interpolation-localization) which allows you to use more readable placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found parametrized localization using String.format to solve this issue.